# Did Francis of Assisi say/write "Start doing what is necessary..."?

Tags: quotes

“Start doing what is necessary, then do what is possible, and suddenly you are doing the impossible” is attributed to St. Francis in thousands of web pages.  But books.google.com can't find it in any book.  scholar.google.com finds the first reference **in a book** by John C. Maxwell in 2011.

I think if Francis said anything similar, it would have been in print before 2000.  But if he said it, he would have said it in Italian or French, so a pre-2000 translation might not have that exact phrasing.

UPDATE: Google found one instance before 1970, on a web page—rather Google **thinks** it was done in January of 1970!  Examination of the page finds a mention of someone dying in 2018, and the quote attributed to **Clare** of Assisi.

Seems that we are not going to get a clear answer from Google, but it does seem that someone made it up not long before 1987 and that it become misattributed to Francis (and Clare).

Comment: Do you know the name of the book?  Can you give a link to the publisher's info?

Comment: Ngram finds uses of the expression in 2003 and 2004.  Eg: https://books.google.com/books?id=OF4SwgWUGQUC&pg=PA1&dq=%22suddenly+you+are+doing%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_wJOMkc3cAhWHn4MKHUavDzc4HhDoAQgzMAI#v=onepage&q=%22suddenly%20you%20are%20doing%22&f=false

Comment: Interesting.  I clicked your link and see that although you used a different substring than I did, the one I used _is_ there but my search didn't find it.  Now to look further...

Comment: It looks like it was first printed in Reader's Digest in 1987. I suspect it is a fake quote sent in by a reader. https://books.google.com/books?id=Zyc0AAAAIAAJ&q="suddenly+you+are+doing+the+impossible"&dq="suddenly+you+are+doing+the+impossible"&hl=en&sa=X

Comment: Weird.  Using Daniel's phrase, I found nothing before 1990 in books.  But adding "the impossible" I found only one instance: Reader's Digest 1987, without citation.  Since that instance does contain the substring Daniel used, clearly Google is suppressing results.

Comment: Even in the best of circumstances, Google's algorithm is "fuzzy".  It's simply impossible to index the amount of data Google does without taking some shortcuts.  The problem is, it's exceedingly difficult to estimate the effect of their actions.

Comment: Hint:  Do searches that explicitly omit dates later than about 1990.

Comment: (Bad publication dates are a common problem with Google.  You can't trust a date unless you can see it on the title page.)

Comment: Without mentioning Francis, I get hits for parts of the above sentence in several 1990-ish books on the saint:  https://www.google.com/search?q=%E2%80%9Cwhat+is+necessary%22+%22do+what+is+possible%22+%22you+are+doing+the+impossible%E2%80%9D&client=firefox-b-1&biw=1122&bih=549&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1700%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2005&tbm=bks

Comment: When I say "only one before X," it is because I specified X as the end date.  Otherwise I could not claim to have viewed all 438 thousand hits to find "only one."  :-)  The link that follows "1990-ish" is to three items 2000, and 2001.  Not really "about the saint" but two of them do attribute the quote to him.

Comment: "Francis and Claire: The Complete Works" certainly seems to be about the saint.  The problem is, of course, that the frustrating copy protection stuff will not let you see the quotes in context, so it's impossible to verify that they're in the book.

Comment: And, interestingly, if you search for the individual words "necessary", "possible", and "impossible", you get hits for just about every philosopher who ever walked the earth.

Comment: Google's selectivity again.  When I clicked the link, the three items that appeared did not include "Francis and Claire: The Complete Works"

Comment: In italian the sentence is used as "Cominciate col fare ciò che è necessario, poi ciò che è possibile. E all'improvviso vi sorprenderete a fare l'impossibile." But that is not italian that St Francis would use. i couldn't find any source.

Comment: January 1970 is the date I get when I screw up trying to convert a timestamp to a date. I'm now suspicious anytime I see this date on a computer.

Comment: Google *kind of* suggests that "Francis and Clare: The Complete Works" by Regis J. Armstrong, 1982 contains something along the lines of the quote.  However, the ability to search within the work is seriously crippled.

Comment: Yeah, if I happen to pass by a library that has it, I might check.

Comment: "If he did, sir, it was strictly off the record!"

Comment: @colmde, just like Abraham Lincoln denying that he said any of the things attributed to him on Facebook?